# Renaming server breaks sql server and sharepoint

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sharepoint

We have had to rename the machine name of a server that was running sql server and SharePoint MOSS. It seems to have broken both, is there a way to resolve this situation?

All the best

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these will help:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261986.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft indicates it can be done.  Some info is here:

[TechNet SharePoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261986.aspx)

I have alos read that it can be a cahllenge and it is easier to rebuild and hasohaimport the SQL data